# Well Cataloged Airplane Sounds

Tags: planes, sound-libraries

Hello Everyone,
I am going to be working on 2 one hour documentaries on naval aviation. There is a need for many airplane SFX ranging from WWI to the modern day.  Because of the nature of the docs and the expected audience, there is a desire for as much accuracy in the sounds of the planes as possible.  Does anyone know of a well cataloged source, commercial or self recorded that I could purchase.  I have some budget but not a tremendous amount.   I already have many of the general commercial libraries, so what I am looking for is something more specific and well cataloged.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This [place](http://www.aircraftrecords.com) may be able to help you. They have an official recording deal with the Reno Air Races.

Comment: Thanks Justin, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I am surprised it didn't come up in any of my searches.

Comment: Awe man! I wish I had asked this question a couple years back when I had to recreate historical dogfight audio with no sources for Military Channel....I ended up finding a model air plane group who sampled the actual planes for playback from their models.  They were stoked to have their recordings on TV and cut me a break by giving me some Japanese Zero samples and some Wildcat recordings. Everything else I had to approximate by looking up which planes were old school prop and which had super chargers, etc. and finding similar engine builds from the sounds I did have.

Comment: Nice link, though there doesn't seem to be any mention on licensing the sounds. It's probably worth checking with Air Craft Records before using them in any work.

Answer (score 0):

[Stephan Shutze's](http://www.stephanschutze.com/) sound library probably has some of what you want, I think. He's recorded sounds from a variety of planes, each in a sizable number of different states. The [Artificial Sounds](http://www.stephanschutze.com/artificial.html) section of his sound library lists them, just look filenames beginning with 'AIRCRAFT,' 'AIRPLANE' and 'AIROPLANE' (Spelling is not his strongest point).

He does charge money, so if you're adverse to paying you might need to look elsewhere.